# How to compare a remote host fingerprint to the fingerprint of a different host?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, remote-desktop

I have two ways of accessing my remote host ssh server:

1. using its local IP addres
2. using its public IP address

Yesterday, I reinstalled my SSH server on the remote host and I updated my known hosts file for the **local IP address**. I am now off of my local network and trying to connect to my server using its **public IP address** and I realized I forgot to update my known hosts file after reinstalling the SSH service. This is giving me the common error below.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
MD5:FINGERPRINT.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:25
ECDSA host key for [PUBLIC IP]:PORT has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I'm 99% sure this is because I changed the SSH server, however, if I wanted to double check and verify, how would I do this?

## My question is

How can I verify the new fingerprint of the remote host against the fingerprint saved for the **local** IP address of the server?

## What I've Done

1. I ran the following command: `ssh-keygen -lv -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts` and found the SHA256 fingerprint saved for the **local** ip address of my server.
2. I compared this to the SHA256 fingerprint being sent to me from my remote host, and they appear to be identical.

**How can I be 100% sure? Did I do this properly?**

Comment: @John That has nothing to do with ssh fingerprints. Those are biometric fingerprints of human fingers

Comment: Yes, if the fingerprints are identical you're good. (To be exact, the host doesn't send the fingerprint; it sends the publickey and your `ssh` program computes and shows the fingerprint.) If you're not using HashKnownHosts, you could let the program do the comparison for you: delete the old line for the public addr, and change the recently-fixed line for the local addr to have both (or all) addresses like `192.168.42.42,111.222.333.444 ecdsa-p256 blahblahblah`.

Comment: What you also did: cross-post this question to https://serverfault.com/questions/1093563/how-to-compare-a-remote-host-fingerprint-to-the-fingerprint-of-a-different-host . See this meta Q/A about this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64069#64069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you did it properly. If you want to have SSH verify it for you, edit your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. Find the line listing your server's local IP address and fingerprint, copy that fingerprint, and use it to replace the old fingerprint on the line for your server's public IP address.